# Run only recently re-built tests in TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild

My team has TFS build machine building checkins.
Today, we have more than a dozen build definitions to prevent building projects/running test in unaffected areas. This was when we weren't using incremental build.
Now that we enabled incremental sync/build, I am thinking about creating one giant gate definition that include all my team's source code. Since incremental sync/build is enabled, unchanged files don't get built anyway. But TFS is still running all tests.
Is there a way to dynamically pick just test assemblies that were built recently?
I can do it by modifying build template to filter out test assemblies that are more x hrs old but before I go that route, I wanted to check if there is something already available.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customizing the template is the right path. Beside the official documentation, take a look at [ALM Rangers' Build Customization Guide](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/).
The FindMatchingFiles activity has no date filtering, so you have to roll your own.